# GET request from 2 APIs in one function (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, api, dom, append

I'm trying to build a page based on CoinGecko APIs.
I was asked to make two different GET request using JQuery, one without parameter, and one with id parameter, but I can't write everything correctly with the second API.

First API gets info about each coin and shows it's symbol and name. Data is shown in a div, one coin per div.
In each div there is a More Info button where data from second GET request is shown. I want to show in More Info div each coin's USD value, EUR value and its image.

I'll be glad to get help with second API,
thanks

```
$(()=>{
    $.get(`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/list`, coins=>{
        for (let i=0; i<100; i++) {
            $(`#homeDiv`).append(`
                <div class="coinCard">
                    <h5><b>${coins[i].symbol}</b></h5>
                    <h6>${coins[i].name}</h6>
                    <button class="moreInfo">More Info</button>  
                </div>
            `)
        };

        // make "More Info" button work
        let infoButtons = $(`.moreInfo`);
        for (let infoButton in infoButtons) {
            $(infoButtons[infoButton]).click(function(e){

                $(()=>{
                    $.get(`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/${coins[i].id}`, coins=>{
                    for (let coin1 of coins) {
                        // console.log(coin.current_price[0].usd)
                        $(e.currentTarget.parentNode).append(`<div>hi${coin.name}
                        </div>`);
                        }     
                    });
                });


            });


        };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use the same index from the loop in the first API call in the click handler for the second call.

A lot of these IDs start with a digit so you won't be able to use them as CSS selectors as is, but you could use something like `<button id="coinid-${coins[i].id}" class="moreInfo">More Info</button>` inside the loop.

Inside your click handler you can then reference the id of each button:

```
let btnid = e.target.id;
let id = btnid.substring(7); // button id without 'coinid-'
```

You would then be able to make the appropriate API call for that particular ID.